# Hibernate legacy collections

Tags: hibernate

there's some hibernate imports :

```
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentCollection;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSortedMap;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSortedSet;
```

that were included in this hibernate dependency :

```
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
            </dependency>
```

but i didn't find them in 4.2.5.Final . what is the path of those inports in recente hibernate version ?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I think that's this is the recent namespace : org.hibernate.collection.internal in hibernate core dependency . :/

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the latest hibernate API for any details.

This is the link to [Hibernate JavaDoc (4.3.6.Final)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/)

and this is the link to [PersistentBag](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentBag.html)